# how to concatenate selected table view strings in ios

Tags: ios

How can I concatenate selected row data from a tableview and store it in an nsstring?

I have taken selected rows with a check mark and individually printed them in the Log. But after selecting 2 or 3 rows, how can I concatenate those strings?

Comment: The key: `- [NSMutableString appendString:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

In .h

```
NSString *yourString;
```

In .m initialize your string in viewDidLoad ,

```
yourString = @"";
```

In  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method

```
yourString = [yourString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",newString];
```

Comment: But when i try this process,it is crashing at the time of second string(table view row) selected.

Comment: Hi,I had set the property synthsise that also,but its crashing and show an error.                                                                           *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet stringByAppendingFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x728d950'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1aeb012 0x1746e7e 0x1b764bd 0x1adabbc 0x1ada94e 0x61ba0 0x73d8d5 0x73db3d 0x1144e83 0x1aaa376 0x1aa9e06 0x1a91a82 0x1a90f44 0x1a90e1b 0x28b47e3 0x28b4668 0x68e65c 0x20472 0x21f5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: @12345 your row data is not a string(cell.textLabel.text)?